# lftp using input file for command input not working

Tags: lftp, ksh

I'm trying to convert from kermit to lftp.  The old script takes the commands from another script for to/from location for the files.  I want to still take that input file, but I'm having trouble getting it to read commands from the input file.

old utils script using kermit:

```
/appl/bin/kermit $M_SCRIPT_TMP_FILE | sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/^/         /' >> ${LOGFILE:-/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/logs/default.log} 2>&1
```

Where kermit version $M_SCRIPT_TMP_FILE contains contents from each script doing ftp (lcd line down) :

```
ftp open MMMMSITE /USER:useruser /PASSWORD:pwpw
LOG TRANSACTIONS /app/tmp/m_Ftp_trans.tmp
  lcd /home/mcleary/k_test/michele/
  cd trans/
  ascii
  put test3.txt
  exit
```

The lftp script using the input file looks like this:

```
 /usr/bin/lftp -f $M_SCRIPT_TMP_FILE | sed -e '/^$/d' -e 's/^/         /' >> ${LOGFILE:-/home/mcleary/k_test/michele/logs/default.log} 2>&1
```

For the lftp version, the input file looks like this:

```
open ftp://useruser:pwpw://MMMMSITE
LOG TRANSACTIONS /app/tmp/m_Ftp_trans.tmp
  lcd /home/mcleary/k_test/michele/
  pwd
  cd trans/
  ls
  put test4.txt
  bye
```

The output/error message for lftp is:

```
open: ftp: Name or service not known
cd: Not connected
ls: Not connected
put: Not connected
Exit Status - m_Ftp2: 0
m_cmd from ckcmd: m_exit
m_log_only from ckcmd:
```

Any ideas why lftp isn't recognizing the ftp input line?

UPDATE: I know lftp works from command line like this, but I need to give input file:

```
lftp -u  useruser,pwpw ftp://MMMMCO <<EOF
> lcd /home/mcleary/k_test/michele/
> cd transfer
> put test.txt
> bye
> EOF
```

UPDATE2: I tried new utils script using lftp like this:

```
open -u useruser,pwpw ftp://MMMMSITE
```

This is output message:

```
cd: Login failed: 530 User cannot log in.
ls: Login failed: 530 User cannot log in.
put: Login failed: 530 User cannot log in.
Exit Status - m_Ftp2: 0
m_cmd from ckcmd: m_exit
m_log_only from ckcmd:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

filename.txt:

```
open ftp://MMMMSITE -u useruser,'pwpw'
  lcd /home/mcleary/k_test/michele/
  pwd
  cd trans/
  ls
  put test5.txt
  bye
```

Then to use that file:

```
lftp -f filename.txt
```